# google OAuth consent screen - Google has not verify this app - "something went wrong"

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, scopes

I'm fetching data from google drive ,first I'm using restricted scope in testing but it give me error that google has not verified this app

```
  Future _signinUser() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
      scopes: [
        drive.DriveApi.driveReadonlyScope,
      ],
    );
    account = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    return;
  }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I fetch data in testing without verify the app from google?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your app isn't verified you can still use it and still authorize it by clicking continue on the screen where it says the app isn't verified instead of clicking back to safety you just have to make sure that you're logged in with the same user that you use to create the account or you have to add the other user as a test user